# How to get JSON file from Zomato for my app...!

Tags: java, android, json, api, zomato-api

I am trying to create an app which displays the hotels nearby. I wanna use zomato api. how to send request and get JSON format output ? 
Am new to android please guide me..!

Comment: https://developers.zomato.com/documentation

Comment: @JoelFernandes ya but how would i retrieve it from ma app??

Comment: What have you tried? Do you think everyone else is here to write your app for you?

Comment: Actually, forget that.. if you write "ya" and "ma"... and can't even be bothered to capitalise an 'I', it's not worth anyone's time helping.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking how to write the code and not referring to a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check some libraries like Volley, Retrofit, OKHttp, etc.

But first you should read the info in Developer.Android.com

[Building Apps with Connectivity](https://developer.android.com/training/building-connectivity.html)

And here are some samples: [Android Samples](https://developer.android.com/samples/connectivity.html)